# NAV2 convert Image to OccupancyGrid Python

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, costmap, nav2

I want to use CostmapFilter for keepout zones in ros2 humble. I found lots of example on how to load an image from file and publish costmap filter.

In my case, user can draw keepout zones dynamically on a map. So I need to be able to publish defined keepout zones dynamically. Keepout zones are defined as a geometry_msgs Polygon array. Each polygon represents a single keepout zone.

To my understanding, I need to publish CostmapFilterInfo message as well as OccupancyGrid message.

I use Python PIL to create an image with proper size (costmap width divided by resolution, costmap height divided by resolution). Also I use ImageDraw of PIL to draw filled polygon. This worked great so far.

What I'm struggling with is how to convert the created Image to an OccupancyGrid? To my  understanding, data of occupancy grid takes values of -127 to 128. I'm not sure what PIL image looks like. I think each pixel gets represented as a tuple for RGB values.

How can I convert the created image to a valid occupancy grid?

```
def publish_keepout_costmap(self):
    # prepare image
    costmap_image = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (int(self.costmap_width / self.costmap_resolution), int(self.costmap_height / self.costmap_resolution)),
                              color ="white") 
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(costmap_image)
    
    # get all keepout zones
    keepout_zones = self.map_provider.get_all_keepout_zones()
    
    # loop through all zones. Draw a polygon for each zone
    for zone in keepout_zones.keepout_zones:
        points =[]
        for point in zone.points:
            points.append((int(point.x / self.costmap_resolution), int(point.y / self.costmap_resolution)))     
        draw.polygon(points, fill="black")
    
    # flip image as image origin is different to ROS map origin    
    costmap_image = costmap_image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    costmap_image.show()
    
    # create publishers
    self.costmap_pub = self.create_publisher(OccupancyGrid, "/ros2mower/costmap_keepout", 3)
    self.costmap_info_pub = self.create_publisher(CostmapFilterInfo, "/ros2mower/costmap_keepout/info", 3)
    
    # create costmap info
    costmap_header = Header()
    costmap_header.frame_id = "map"
    costmap_header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
    costmap_info = CostmapFilterInfo
    costmap_info.filter_mask_topic = "/ros2mower/costmap_keepout"
    costmap_info.type = 0
    costmap_info.base = 10
    costmap_info.multiplier = 1
    costmap_info.header = costmap_header
    
    costmap_meta = MapMetaData()
    costmap_meta.height = self.costmap_height
    costmap_meta.width = self.costmap_width
    costmap_meta.resolution = self.costmap_resolution


       costmap_data = OccupancyGrid()
        costmap_data.header = costmap_header
        costmap_data.info = costmap_meta

====>>> here trouble starts =====>>>
        costmap_data.data = costmap_image
 

   
    self.costmap_pub.publish(costmap_data)
    self.costmap_info_pub.publish(costmap_info)
```